# Is it bad practice to use dependency injection in factory classes?

Tags: java, spring, factory-pattern

Is it bad practice to use dependency injection in factory classes? Should I let the users of my framework take care of dependency injection? Should I use approach A or approach B?

*SomeUserClass*

```
package com.impl;

@Service
public class SomeUserClass {

    @Autowired
    private SMSActionFactoryService actionFactoryService:

    @Autowired
    private PropertyManager properties;

    public void doStuff(){
        // approach A
        SMSAction action = actionFactoryService.createAction("hello");

        // approach B
        action = SMSActionFactory.createAction(properties, "hello");

        // the user should never call Action::doAction. 
        // It gets called by the framework on a condition.
        scheduler.addAction(State.ERROR, action)
    }

}
```

*SMSAction*

```
package com.framework;

public class SMSAction extends Action {

    public SMSAction(PropertyManager properties, String message){

    }

    public void doAction(){
    }

}
```

*SMSActionFactoryService*

```
package com.framework;

@Service
public class SMSActionFactoryService {

    @Autowired
    private PropertyManager properties;

    public SMSActionFactory createAction(String message) {
        return new SMSActionFactoryService(properties, message);
    }
}
```

*SMSActionFactory*

```
package com.framework;

public class SMSActionFactory {

    public static SMSActionFactory createAction(PropertyManager properties, String message) {
        return new SMSActionFactory(properties, message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Approach A makes unit testing easy.  Approach B makes unit testing a pain.     Avoid pain!  (And follow TDD or at least write unit tests soon after to quickly discover code smells.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a context problem, so the answer depends on the context. But I'll give some of my experience, and not a formal (and irrefutable) answer. Based on the title of the answer (practices) I'll give you what I call *good practices* tips that helped me a lot when I started Spring development.

First of all, let's think about the *Dependency Injection* you have. You're wiring a field, and we know that the Spring team used to suggest us to use constructor based injection (and assertions for all mandatory dependency) as you can see [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/11/29/how-not-to-hate-spring-in-2016#injection). Well, I know it was a problem with the tests framework that couldn't wire the dependencies in an easy way, but now *they can*. But there's another advantage using this pattern, you can make your bean field `final`. Another advantage is that you prevent circular dependencies, like X depends on Y and Y depends on X and so on. So, as the first tip, I would suggest you to use something like:

```
private final SMSActionFactoryService actionFactoryService:
private final PropertyManager properties;

@Autowired
public SomeUserClass(SMSActionFactoryService actionFactoryService,
                     PropertyManager properties) {
     Assert.notNull(actionFactoryService, "The actionFactoryService bean is null, you should provide the bean to run this application");
     Assert.notNull(properties, "The properties bean is null, you should provide the bean to run this application");

     this.actionFactoryService = actionFactoryService;
     this.properties = properties;
}
```

This way you prevent any other code part to change the field value. As you can see in [Spring autowiring setter/constructor PROs and CONs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686462/spring-autowiring-setter-constructor-pros-and-cons) this is a preference subject.

Now, for the second tip, I wouldn't use `@Service` for a factory, not even `@Component` because factories needs to be *open for extension and close for modification*. You're going to understand better if take a look [here](http://csc.columbusstate.edu/woolbright/Java/factory.html).

That said friend, I suggest you to **embrace approach B**.

Comment: The SomeUserClass is not part of the framework, it is just an implementation example. There are different ActionFactory classes, so I can't just pass a Factory to the user. The user has to learn about the different ActionFactory classes and inject them itself.

Comment: Well, I could add an ActionFactoryGodClass which can create all different Actions, but I don't think thats a good approach.